# How can I know the height of a superview after I change one of its subview like UILabel

Tags: ios

I change the My UILabel's text and make it become multiple lines. I guess the the superview of this label will resize after that. But how to get the new frame of the superview as soon as I change the label.text?

Comment: Superviews usually don't change dimensions based on their subviews contents.

Comment: I draw a UIView in Interface Builder and add a UILabel to it. When I change the text of this label I want to get the updated height of that UIView. Is that possible?

Answer (score 0):

```
CGSize size = labelSuperview.size;
```